# Full object not loaded for access within razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have created a controller that will get back all relevant data using a "UnitOfWork" which adopts a repository pattern.

```
using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork())
{
    var question = unitOfWork.QuestionRepository.GetById(id);
    return View(question);
}
```

This question object that is returned from the unit of work contains a property called "User" which is a navigation property within the Entity Framework model. After I have gotten back this object I pass this object to a view. The problem I have is that once I try to access this property and any of the further sub properties on this "User" property, I get an error of:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

I am not sure how I am supposed to get the foreign key attributes of the Question object model as connection to the database has been closed by the time the object is within the view. I have tried to create a special "GetById" function within my repository pattern but this hasn't worked for me, the error still arises regardless of using:

```
_databaseEntities.Set<TEntity>().Include("User")
```

What would the solution to this problem be?

Answer (score 0):

In the repository implementation when you fetch the Question, do this:

```
_databaseEntities.Questions.Include(q => q.User).FirtstOrDefault(q => q.Id == id);
```

When you return the **`Question`** entity, it should already have the **`User`** entity.